# Git Submodule - Unable to Access Repository using Linux Subsystem for Windows

Tags: windows, git, git-submodules, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to add a Git submodule to a different repository. I created the repository I want it in, but the submodule was created by my advisor.

For convenience, let's say the submodule I'm trying to add is repository A and the one I'm trying to add it to is repository B.

A couple of notes:

1. I'm using the Linux Subsystem for Windows (i.e., the Ubuntu terminal app).
2. I have an active internet connection and can access both repositories via the standard git commands (git pull, push, commit, etc.)
3. I can get all my code working fine using symbolic links to A.

Here are the steps I'm taking to add A to B, and the corresponding terminal outputs.

```
In: git submodule add git@gitlab.com:Respository_B
```

The above line worked fine, and I can see the correct info in the .gitmodules file, this is the output:

```
[submodule "Repository_B"]       
    path = repository_B
    url = git@gitlab.com:Repsitory_B
```

Now, I tried the following two things:

```
In: git submodule init
Out: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'submodule_A' in .gitmodules
```

and,

```
In: git submodule update --remote
Out: setsockopt IPV6_TCLASS 8: Operation not permitted:
```

I'm stumped. I tried searching for a solution online, but came up empty-handed. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Also, if I need to clarify anything, please let me know.

Thank you!

---

EDIT

---

I [just read](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115564/wsl-ubuntu-distro-how-to-solve-operation-not-permitted-on-cloning-repository) that there are some chmod issues with the Windows subsystem, so I tried this line and got a different error message.

```
In:  sudo git submodule update --remote 
Out: git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey). 
     fatal: Could not read from remote repository. 

     Please make sure you have the correct access rights
     and the repository exists.
     Unable to fetch in submodule path 'Repository_A'
```

This is weird, because I am able to access the repository using a symbolic link I made to a local clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to add is repository A and the one I'm trying to add it to is repository B.

Then the command would be:

```
cd /path/to/B
git submodule add git@gitlab.com:Respository_A
git commit -m "Add A to B"
git push
```

Regarding the error message, [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1869#issuecomment-357160491) suggests:

> A workaround that we are using is to put the following line in ~/.ssh/config:
>
> ```
> AddressFamily inet
> ```
>
> Note: Using AddressFamily inet works great if you're connecting to an IPv4 host. If the host is IPv6 only, it won't connect at all.

Comment: I don't have a config file in my .ssh folder, I'm assuming I'll have to add a new one here? Also, I am on a IPv6 network.

Comment: @Kosta You can add such a file. And I am talking about the destination host, not your own network.

Comment: Okay, so that workaround was successful. The only thing was that I had to use sudo to give it the correct permissions.

Comment: But, my issue still persists. I cannot access any of the classes in repository A.

Comment: @Kosta The point of the answer was to higlight how to add A to B. In your question, you have added B to A.

Comment: Everything works! For future people reading this, make sure to add a symbolic link from the folder where your script is to Repository_A.